# При запуске задачи из командной строки в ручную результат один, если через cron(laravel schedule), результат другой. В чем разница?

Tags: laravel, php7, cron

Laravel 7. Код команды простой -

```
protected $signature = 'service:cron'; 
public function handle()
    {
        // check ticker
        $cmd = "echo $(ps aux | grep 'daemon:ticker' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')";
        exec($cmd, $output, $return);
        Log::info($output[0]);
    }
```

Когда в консоли набираю `php artisan service:cron` в логе нормальный ответ 
`local.INFO: 27306`.

Если через Schedule в kernel.php, к примеру так

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('service:cron')->everyMinute();
    }
```

или даже через crontab

```
* * * * *       cd path_to_service && php artisan service:cron >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

то ответ пустой.

```
local.INFO:
```

Демон работает.
Может кто то объяснить в чем разница ?

Comment: Проверь пользователя, от имени которого выполняется Cron

Comment: cron под тем же пользователем что и запуск в ручную

Comment: Попробуй убрать "/dev/null" и/или "2>&1"

Comment: Все-таки я на 99% уверен, что проблема именно в пользователе, от имени которого запускается крон процесс. Залогируй из крона команду `echo $USER`